# You can run "adb shell dpm set-profile-owner" from java android?

Tags: java, android

I am making a launcher type application where I request administrator permissions, but I also need administrator permissions in the profile, I found the way and it is with
`adb shell dpm set-device-owner [your.package]/.DeviceAdminReceiver`,
but that is in a console from the pc.

Is there a way to do it from java or some alternative to have administrator permissions in the device profile?

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner [your.package]/.DeviceAdminReceiver`,